# Remove Hashbang on VueJs with Laravel

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have already tried the suggestions stated regarding the hashbang (/#/) with Vue and Laravel, and it seems it still doesn't work for me.

routes.js

```
let routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        component: Home,
        children: [
            {
                path: '/blog',
                component: PageBlogLists,
            },
            {
                path: '/post/:page_id',
                component: PageBlog
            }
        ]
    },
];

export default new VueRouter({
    // This does not work
    mode: 'history',
    routes
});
```

app.js

```
// Vue Router
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import router from './router/routes';

require('./bootstrap');
window.Vue = require('vue');
Vue.use(VueRouter);


const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router
});
```

Has anyone successfully tried removing it?

Comment: try adding also `hash: false` after `mode: history`

Comment: @sebasaenz still the same .. doesn't work